# Set the Storyboard guide title to a @IBInspectable value for a custom @IBDesignable view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I have a custom @IBDesignable UIButton. I use several of them on a screen in the Storyboard file and they are central to the whole flow of the app. They all appear in the Guide as "Button":

["Button"s in guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36tJ0.jpg)

Seeing the actual title would be a whole lot easier in managing the Storyboard (although of course has no effect on actual runtime). I'd like to set the title to an @IBInspectable label text I'm using:

[Their attribute Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOnbU.jpg)

I'm using my own label text instead of the regular button title because it's layout and format is special. If I set the button title it shows up in the middle over the real title.

Ideally I want to set the guide "title" to my label. I couldn't find anything anywhere on how to do this. Otherwise, is there some work around trick to use the Button Label? Keep in mind this is just to make the Storyboard less confusing for others to see and use.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you just rename each Button in Storyboard without changing the title attribute?

Comment: Thanks guys. These buttons will be moved around, edited, and point to different segues. Manually editing the guide titles won't necessarily continue to match what it actual is. (This is a problem I had a few times when I started with Storyboards, the edited title no longer matching what it really was and causing more confusion.)

Comment: If it's possible to automatically rename the guide title (just like how the UIButton title works) that would be ideal. If not, I'm not sure if manually editing really subtracts from the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can always slow double click each button (in the Document Outline (the left pane (your first picture))). It'll let you rename it right there.

By "slow double click" I mean, click to select, wait a sec, click again (without moving the mouse).

I'm only familiar with The Document Outline automatically naming things when you provide referencing outlets (control dragging to a .swift file). They'll take on the names of the variables you're dragging them to (even so far as formatting camel case with spaces and caps for you). Otherwise, in your case, you're probably going to have to manually name each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can "name" your elements by filling in the `Label` field in the Identity Inspector pane:

[image]

As you see, I have a normal UIButton, and I put "Button One" in the Label field... so it shows up as "Button One" in the outline pane.